# Add custom tags to sanitized_allowed_tags without replacing defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add custom tags to `ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_tags` for `sanitize()` method.

As written in the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html), i have to add an config option in `application.rb` like below to append new custom tags :

```
# In config/application.rb
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ['strong', 'em', 'a']
```

But when i set a new tag like :

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ["nav"]
```

It replace the default tags `["strong", "em", "b", "i", ...]` with only ["nav"].
The only workaround i found is to re-declare the whole default array with the new tags merged :

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ["nav", "strong", "em", "b", "i", ...]
```

I also tried `config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags += ["nav"]` but by default `sanitized_allowed_tags` is null.

There is an better way to add tags without re-declaring the defaults ones at application level ?

I'm using Ruby on Rails v5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in an `after_initialize` block:

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_tags.add 'nav'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 6, `sanitized_allowed_tags` and `sanitized_allowed_attributes` are not class methods.

You can add your values like following:

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = Rails::Html::SafeListSanitizer.allowed_attributes.add('target')
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = Rails::Html::SafeListSanitizer.allowed_tags.add('u')
```

Comment: Um... no, this is wrong. It does not work in Rails 6: `uninitialized constant Rails::Html (NameError)`

Comment: @railsfanatic `Rails::Html` exists in `rails-html-sanitizer` gem, which is a dependency of `actionview`.